# Ubuntu 20.04 — Cannot not install solc

Tags: 20.04, ethereum

When I use `sudo apt-get install solc`, I receive the following error:

```
Unable to locate package solc
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the Ethereum PPA to your system?

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt update
sudo apt install solc
```

There’s also a snap version if you prefer:

```
sudo snap install solc
```

If you prefer the daily builds, then:

```
sudo snap install solc --edge
```